# Any tutorial on integrating SmartGWT and JasperReports?

Tags: java, gwt, jasper-reports, smartgwt

I need to integrate Reports within my GWT/SmartGWT web application. I have not found any tutorial that can guide me on how to integrate SmartGWT and Jasper Reports, so I'm concerned whether it's possible at all.

Please respond if you have any information on this topic.

Comment: There is java [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html). Another java API for JasperReports is [DynamicJasper API](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/xref/)

Comment: Are those APIs supported by client code of SmartGWT

Comment: Is any java library (framework) supported by SmartGWT?

Comment: Agree with you Alex, only small subset of java library is supported by SmartGWT/GWT client. I have hypothetical solution in my mind, 1. generate report server side 2. put it at temporary location at server 3. Provide a link to download it. I just wanted to confirm whether I am in right direction and if I am missing something then proven tutorial could be a better guide :)

Comment: The [JasperServer](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperserver) is a standalone web-application which has [web services](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/WebServices). You can try to use web services, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find *any* PDF or reporting libraries that run client-side with GWT. The thing is, all of the processing to generate a report and send it back to the browser needs to be done on the server. Your best bet is to try to check out [something like this](https://github.com/dipti/IText-GWT-assignment) and learn from the code. While that specific example is for iText, the concepts are exactly the same. That's about the best you're going to get until someone decides to release a GWT version of a PDF library.

Eventually, maybe the guys at iText or JasperSoft will decide to make a GWT wrapper for their libraries, but the truth is that it would be (more or less) the same as the link above. Maybe *slightly* more integrated with GWT.

Comment: Looking for something like this only. I will try to put a blog on this once I am done with this implementation

Comment: @BhaveshShah That doesn't make my answer any less accurate. Your question was about a library of **client-side code** that generates PDF reports, and there is no such library.

Comment: I am not limiting my self for generating PDF reports only. I will need to generate excel, csv etc. too. I understand now that there is no such library at client-side who facilitates this. I am going to implement server side code that will take advantage of spring and jasper reports to prepare reports and after that application client will be able to display reports on supported GWT/SmartGWT Widget.

Comment: @BhaveshShah The point is that you asked if there was a client-side library that could do what you need, and I correctly answered that question.

Comment: Aah..Just started using stackoverflow so I am adapting to its rules.. forgot to mark it as answer.